# Execute command with special characters from user input

Tags: vimscript, command, user-input

I would like to correctly intepret the `<cr>` in a command that is created based on user input.

For example, this function runs correctly and it will split the line a the location where the cursor is.

```
function NewLine()
  execute "normal! r\<cr>"
endfunction
```

But if I convert it to accept user input:

```
function NewLine()
  let l:cmd = input('Your command: ')
  execute "normal! " . l:cmd
endfunction
```

if the input is `r\<cr>` then it just replaces the character the current cursor is on, with `\` instead of spliting the line.

How to make it interpret the whole thing, as it seems it stops at `\`.

Comment: I would use `r` `CTRL-V` `ENTER` in your input

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks 

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to be able to enter a sequence such as `r\<cr>` or `r\r` and have Vim interpret that the same way as it interprets sequences in a double quoted string, the easiest way to do so is to actually assemble it into a double quoted string and use [`eval()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#eval%28%29) to have Vim interpret it.

In your particular case:

```
execute "normal! " . eval('"' . l:cmd . '"')
```

Note that there's potential for the produced string to be invalid. For example, if `l:cmd` includes a single double quote in it. So you might want to make sure you're using the [`try` command](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Atry) to catch any errors when evaluating the string you produced.

It's also important to notice that there's potential that a clever user might exploit this to have `l:cmd` evaluate to a function that has potential side effects, so make sure you make some due diligence to prevent expression injection in this scheme, particularly if you're interpreting sequences coming from a file that might have been downloaded from the web. (There was a recent security vulnerability in Vim that could be exploited by simply opening a file with a specially crafted modeline. When you're using something like `eval()`, make sure you're not creating something that's opening the door to such types of exploits.)

Comment: For the double quote, couldn’t you use something like `escape(..., '"\')`?

Comment: @Ben Yes, you can escape things such as `"` and backslash, but since the question was using `r\<cr>` as an example, escaping backslash would have prevented this from solving that particular case... `eval()` is evil, so I'd rather just point out that dragons lie ahead rather than try to take on them myself 